# Missing implicit TypedType[JsonString] with slick-pg

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-pg

I am using slick-pg 0.8.2 with Slick 2.1.0 and am having problems with a JSON-typed column.

My Driver is defined as follows:

```
trait PgsqlDriver extends PostgresDriver
                          with PgJsonSupport
                          with array.PgArrayJdbcTypes
                          with PgDateSupportJoda
                          with PgSearchSupport {
  override val pgjson = "jsonb"

  override lazy val Implicit = new ImplicitsPlus { }
  override val simple = new SimpleQLPlus {}

  trait ImplicitsPlus extends Implicits
                              with DateTimeImplicits
                              with JsonImplicits
                              with SearchImplicits

  trait SimpleQLPlus extends SimpleQL
                             with ImplicitsPlus
                             with SearchAssistants
}

object PgsqlDriver extends PostgresDriver
```

This is my Table class (it's abstract since I have several tables with the same structure and I subclass from this one):

```
private[ pgsql ] abstract class PgsqlTable[ D <: DomainObject[ D ] ](tag: Tag, tableName: String)
    extends Table[ JsonBean ](tag, tableName) {
  import PgsqlDriver.simple._

  def id = column[ String ]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def json = column[ JsonString ]("JSON", O.NotNull)

  override def * = (id, json) <> (JsonBean.tupled, JsonBean.unapply)
}
```

As far as I can see, this is all according to the tests, examples and the docs on the slick-pg site. However, I'm getting the following compilation error on the `def json =` line:

```
Error:(23, 34) could not find implicit value for parameter tm:     scala.slick.ast.TypedType[com.github.tminglei.slickpg.JsonString]
  def json = column[ JsonString ]("JSON", O.NotNull)
                             ^
```

Comment: possibly related issue on github: https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/104

Comment: are you sure you're importing the correct `JsonImplicits` -- not the one from `Play` or `Json4s` or others?

Comment: @BenReich: I tried the solution in the possibly related issue, but no go. According to IntelliJ, the `JsonImplicits` I'm importing are from `PgJsonSupport`, so it seems they are the right ones. I also tried using `PgJson4sSupport` and using `JValue` instead of `JsonString`, but got the same problem.

Comment: Got it! My problem was in the last line, `object PgsqlDriver extends PostgresDriver` instead of `extends PgsqlDriver`. D'oh!

Comment: Ah yes I see.  Well you should answer your own question since you resolved it!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! My problem was in the last line, `object PgsqlDriver extends PostgresDriver` instead of `extends PgsqlDriver`.